# Print SQL-Variable in ColdFusion

Tags: sql, variables, coldfusion

how can I print a SQL-variable in Coldfusion?

```
<cfquery...>
  ...
  @var1='whatever'
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
  #@var1#
</cfoutput>
```

A syntax like this is always throwing an error because of the `@` symbol.

Comment: a storedproc may help.

Comment: How would a storedproc help?

Comment: Unlike cfquery, stored procs support returning output variables and multiple result sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. `<cfquery>` sends the SQL string to the DB and expects a record set back. That's the only thing `<cfquery>` exposes to the calling code. It doesn't in any way parser (or understand in any way) the SQL statement... it simply sends it on to the DB. CF doesn't know there's an SQL variable in there.

What you'd need to do is something like this (untested):

```
<cfquery name="blah">
    ...
    @var1='whatever'

    SELECT @var AS someName
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>#blah.someName#</cfoutput>
```

Doing it that way will mean the recordset which is returned (which is always the <s>last</s>[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981922/print-sql-variable-in-coldfusion/27982307?noredirect=1#comment44367092_27982307) one in the SQL statement) will be the one with your variable in it.

Comment: Thanks, but the variable i want to print out is composed of several values from inside a loop. Besides i can't do a select on this var because it's 'undefined'...

Comment: Shrug. You might wanna look @ using a proc instead inline SQL then, I think. Bottom line: you cannot access a var in the SQL string `<cfquery>` passed to the DB. `<cfquery>` only returns record sets.

Comment: Another possibility is to throw the values into a temp table, and do a SELECT at the end. All depends on what you are returning. (While you might be able to do that in a cfquery, I would stick with a stored proc. Those are better suited for complex sql statements.)

Comment: *..the recordset which is returned (which is always the last one in the SQL statement) ...*  Adam - Actually, CF returns the first statement to generate a resultset.

Comment: Why don't you include the variable in your select clause?

Comment: @Leigh. D'oh! I knew I should have verified that first ;-) Cheers for the heads-up mate

Comment: Welcome :) I only remembered it because the first resultset issue was (tangentially) related to problems with result.identity and the sql server driver, back in CF8. Boy was that fun..